# Protractor cannot find element after page has loaded

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

Seems like a common question, but can't find anything corresponding to my issue.

My test runs fine until it reloads the page and needs to catch an element from dropdown. First I tried using IsPresent to see if Protractor can find the wrapper were dropdown lies called "workbenchItems" and I also added a long sleep, but it doesn't work, and then of course it can't catch the dropdown aswell - the element I need to catch is in the last row called: 'Element from dropdown that I need to catch'

See the Protractor code here:

```html
<div class="workbenchItems">
    <div data-uib-accordion="" data-close-others="false" data-template- url="modules/common/accordion/accordion.tpl.html">
        <div role="tablist" class="panel-group accordion" ng-transclude="">
            <div data-uib-accordion-group="" ng-click="$ctrl.setIsOpen($ctrl.itemIndex, $ctrl.isOpen)" class="panel-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel panel-open"
                data-template-url="modules/common/accordion/accordion-group.tpl.html" data-nobody="true"
                data-leveltitle="h3" data-is-open="$ctrl.isOpen">
                <div class="panel-heading no-bottom-border" data-ng-class="{'no-bottom-border': noBody}" style="">
                    <h2 class="panel-title"><a href="" tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()"
                            uib-accordion-transclude="heading"><span uib-accordion-header="" ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}"
                                ng-bind-html="heading" class="ng-binding">
                                <div class="ng-scope"><span ng-bind="::$ctrl.item.sectionName" class="ng-binding">Element
                                        from dropdown that I need to catch</span> <span class="count ng-binding"
                                        ng-bind="::$ctrl.item.sectionCount">2159</span></div>
                            </span></a></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse in collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"
                    style="">
```

This is what I've tried to catch the second element from the row

```
const toolaud = await element.all(by.tagName('accordion-toggle')).get(1);
     toolaud.click();
     browser.waitForAngular();
     browser.sleep(60 * 1000);
```

Comment: what is `browser.waitForAngular();`

Comment: Took it from here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular

But that doesn't matter, it doesn't work even if I remove it. 

Maybe it's some sort of a nested element issue? Or what could it be.

Just tried it with xpath, doesn't work either..

Comment: `tagName('accordion-toggle')` i dont find tag name as `accordion-toggle` and maybe there is no such tagname

Comment: @Tina86 Use `element(by.css("h2.panel-title a"))` instead of `element.all(by.tagName('accordion-toggle')).get(1)`

Comment: Saddam thanks a lot, that worked! But how can I click the first one? Since there are many panel-titles..

Comment: Since your page does a manual refresh, is the error message around bootstrap and cannot find testability? What is the error message?

Comment: The test just ignores this step and finishes. I got passed that with Saddam's help, but I can't click the first element, gives me element not found error.

Comment: @Tina86 Can you try this `$$("h2.panel-title a").get(0).click()`

Comment: @Tina86 add a try catch and check the error (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
also try to build the xpath with (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `by.css("h2.panel-title a")` instead of `by.tagName('accordion-toggle')`

### Solution:

```
element.all(by.css("h2.panel-title a")).get(0);
```

As there are many panel titles, the above code will get you the first panel title.
You can provide the value of index in `get()` function to get the respective panel title.
If you provide 2 as index like `get(2)` then it will get 3rd panel title [Indexing start from 0 and not 1].

**Explanation:**

`h2.panel-title a` means:

Search for `h2` tag element which has class `panel-title`. After that, search for `a` tag inside that found tag HTML code.

---

### Additional Information:

1. If there is only 1 panel title, then there is 1 more way to solve the same problem.

   ```
   element(by.css("h2.panel-title a"));
   ```
2. `$$("h2.panel-title a").get(0)` and `element.all(by.css("h2.panel-title a")).get(0)` have same meaning and works the same way. It is always better to keep the same syntax everywhere. So, it becomes less confusing to other developers. If you use `element()` or `element.all()` syntax instead of `$()` and `$$()`, then I would suggest to keep the syntax same and not change it, even if both the syntax produces the same result.